# Semantic UI sidebar scrolling issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, semantic-ui

I have a website I have created using the framework Semantic UI where when you have a screen the size of a phone you have the option of using a sidebar. Currently it all works fine apart from when you click on it you can then not scroll nor open any popout tabs within the header. Here is my code, if anyone could help that'd be great!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html scroll-behavior: smooth;>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Diana website 0.1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic/dist/semantic.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainStyleSheet.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/semantic-ui/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/formantic-ui/modal.js"></script>

    <script src="semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body class="pushable" data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.1106.0" data-gr-ext-installed="">


    <!-- side menu -->
    <div class="ui left vertical inverted sidebar menu">
        <a class="active item">
            1
        </a>
        <a class="item">
            2
        </a>
        <a class="item">
            3
        </a>
    </div>


    <!-- Page contents -->

    <div class="pusher">
        
        <div class="ui vertical masthead center aligned segment" style="background-color:#d8d5b7" id="header">

            <div class="ui container">

                <div class="ui fluid secondary  menu">


                    <div class="ui fluid tiny image" id="logo"> <img src="images\yogalogo.png"></div>

                    <div class="ui right secondary menu" id="headercontent">
                        <a class="active item" href="#HomeFirst"
                            style="color:#797657;font-family:Calibri;font-weight: bold;"
                            onclick="activeItem('HomeFirst')">Home</a>







                        <a class="browse item" style="color:#797657;font-family:Calibri;font-weight: bold;">
                            Classes & Services
                            <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                        </a>

                        <div class="ui large popup">
                            <div class="ui grid">
                                <div class="ui button four wide row" id="HeaderTabContent"
                                    onmouseenter="runAnimation('1')" onmouseleave="runAnimation('1')">
                                    <div class="visible content">Public classes</div>

                                    <i class="right arrow icon 1"></i>

                                </div>
                                <div class="ui horizontal divider"></div>
                                <div class="ui button four wide row" id="HeaderTabContent"
                                    onmouseenter="runAnimation('2')" onmouseleave="runAnimation('2')">
                                    <div class="visible content">Yoga for teachers</div>

                                    <i class="right arrow icon 2"></i>

                                </div>
                                <div class="ui horizontal divider"></div>
                                <div class="ui button four wide row" id="HeaderTabContent"
                                    onmouseenter="runAnimation('3')" onmouseleave="runAnimation('3')">
                                    <div class="visible content">Trauma informed Yoga</div>

                                    <i class="right arrow icon 3"></i>

                                </div>
                                <div class="ui horizontal divider"></div>
                                <div class="ui button four wide row" id="HeaderTabContent"
                                    onmouseenter="runAnimation('4')" onmouseleave="runAnimation('4')">
                                    <div class="visible content">Individual Trauma
                                        informed yoga</div>

                                    <i class="right arrow icon 4"></i>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>




                        <a class="item" href="#HomeSecond" id="homeSecond"
                            style="color:#797657;font-family:Calibri;font-weight: bold;"
                            onclick="activeItem('homeSecond')">About</a>
                        <a class="item" href="#Contact" id="contact"
                            style="color:#797657;font-family:Calibri;font-weight: bold;"
                            onclick="activeItem('contact')">Contact</a>



                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button id="left-sidebar-toggle" class="ui button two"><i class="huge align justify icon"></i></button>

        <div class="ui fluid container" id="HomeFirst">
            <div class="centered">Diane Dupres <br><br> Yoga & Wellness</div>
            <div class="down-arrow"></div>
        </div>





        <div class="ui fluid container" id="HomeSecond">
            <div class="ui paddedcenter aligned segment" id="HomeSecondContent">
                <div class="centered" id="HomeSecondContentTitle">
                    About
                </div>
                <p id="HomeSecondContenttext">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                    et
                    dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                    aliquip
                    ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
                    dolore eu
                    fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
                    deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </p>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ui fluid container" id="Contact">
            <div class="centered" id="HomeSecondContentTitle">
                Contact






            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">



        $('.ui.left.sidebar').sidebar({
            dimPage: false,
            transition: 'push',
            exclusive: false,
            closable: false
        });

        $('.ui.left.sidebar')
            .sidebar('attach events', '#left-sidebar-toggle');

        $('.browse')
            .popup({
                on: 'click',
                inline: true,
                hoverable: true,
                position: 'bottom center',
                delay: {
                    show: 300,
                    hide: 800
                }
            })
            ;

        function runAnimation(number) {
            $('.right.arrow.icon.' + number).transition('fade left');
        }

        function activeItem(NameOfActive) {

        }

    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

I have messed around with sizing, different ways to call the sidebar, literally everything I can think of.